# Custom progress indicator with GIF image

Tags: flutter, dart, gif, progress

I want to make a dialog for progress indicator. I want to use GIF file.

This is the gif image:

[image: This is je gif image]

Comment: you can use the package from pub.dev or use the gif only

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to display the gif within the dialog box. You can do something like this:

```dart
// Currently transparent, change this to your desired background color
var _backgroundColor = Colors.transparent;

showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierColor: _backgroundColor,
  builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
    return AlertDialog(
      backgroundColor: _backgroundColor,
      content: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/test.gif', // Put your gif into the assets folder
            width: 100,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Just a quick note, the GIF you chose have a solid background color. If you want to only display the progress indicator, you have 3 options:

- Remove the background from the gif
- Choose a gif with transparent background
- Set the _backgroundColor to the same color as the background from the gif

P/s: Another options is to design an animation yourself using Flare/ Rive but it's a bit advance. You can [read more here](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/flutter-animation-with-flare-3863e8ff5030)